# clearInterval is not working

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is above something I want to showcase, and I have the `setInterval` working, but the `clearInterval` isn’t firing when it reaches 2 loops.

I have this:

```
window.setInterval(play_ani_clickthese, 3000);
var fade_count = 0;

function play_ani_clickthese() {
    $("#click_these").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    fade_count += parseInt('1');

    if(fade_count == 2) window.clearInterval(play_ani_clickthese);
}
```

But when the 'fade_count' reaches 2, it just keeps going.

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `clearInterval` takes the ID of the interval, not a function. It is described in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.clearInterval

Comment: [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.clearInterval) is a javascript function, not specific to the jQuery framework at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
var id = window.setInterval(play_ani_clickthese, 3000);
clearInterval(id);
```

Comment: Perfect! changed everything to this:
 var id = window.setInterval(play_ani_clickthese, 3000);
 var fade_count = 0;
 function play_ani_clickthese() {
  $("#click_these").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
  fade_count+=parseInt('1');
  if(fade_count == 2){clearInterval(id);}
 }